# Orbeon JavaScript embedding visibility formula error: `_.detect is not a function`

Tags: javascript, orbeon

I am using the JS embedding API of Orbeon. I have experienced an error forcing me to refresh the website when I have a `fr:yesno` control's visibility depending on another yesno value. The error is presented in orbeon's dialog, the browser console is empty.
The error produced is:

```
Exception in client-side code.
* Message: TypeError: _.detect is not a function
```

The specific formula causing the problem is:

```xml
<xf:bind id="control-2-bind" ref="control-2" name="control-2" type="xs:boolean"
         relevant="$control-1/string() = 'true'"
         required="true()"/>
...
<fr:yesno-input bind="control-1-bind" ...>
<fr:yesno-input bind="control-2-bind" ...>
```

On the other hand this does not make a problem:

```xml
<xf:bind id="control-6-bind" ref="control-6" name="control-6"
         relevant="$control-5/string() = 'false'"/>
...
<fr:yesno-input bind="control-5-bind" ...>
<fr:explanation bind="control-6-bind" ...>
```

---

I have tried to use the `xxf:is-control-relevant('control-2-control')` function in the visibility formula to progressively build the `relevant` attribute (to achieve transitive invisibility), but it does not work as expected, because the function seems to return an old value when changing the relevant yesno value.

---

My question is: How to fix the error while using JS embedding?

---

Full form definition to reproduce

```xml
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
         xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
         xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
         xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
         xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
         xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
         xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
         xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
         xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
         xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
         xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
         fr:data-format-version="4.0.0">
    <xh:head>
        <xh:title>JavaScript Embedding</xh:title>
        <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true" xxf:analysis.calculate="true">

            
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" xxf:index="id">
                <form>
                    <section-1>
                        <grid-1>
                            <control-1/>
                            <control-2/>
                            <control-3/>
                            <control-5/>
                            <control-6/>
                        </grid-1>
                        
                    </section-1>
                </form>
            </xf:instance>

            
            <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
                <xf:bind id="section-1-bind" name="section-1" ref="section-1">
                    <xf:bind id="grid-1-bind" ref="grid-1" name="grid-1">
                        <xf:bind id="control-1-bind" ref="control-1" name="control-1" type="xs:boolean"
                                 required="true()"/>
                        <xf:bind id="control-2-bind" ref="control-2" name="control-2" type="xs:boolean"
                                 relevant="$control-1/string() = 'true'"
                                 required="true()"/>
                        <xf:bind id="control-3-bind" ref="control-3" name="control-3" type="xs:decimal"
                                 relevant="$control-1/string() = 'true' and $control-2/string() = 'true'"
                                 required="true()"/>
                        <xf:bind id="control-5-bind" ref="control-5" name="control-5" type="xs:boolean"
                                 required="true()"/>
                        <xf:bind id="control-6-bind" ref="control-6" name="control-6"
                                 relevant="$control-5/string() = 'false'"/>
                    </xf:bind>
                    
                </xf:bind>
            </xf:bind>

            
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:readonly="true" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <metadata>
                    <application-name>Test</application-name>
                    <form-name>EmbedJS</form-name>
                    
                    <title xml:lang="en">JavaScript Embedding</title>
                    <description xml:lang="en"/>
                    <created-with-version>2020.1.202012300129 PE</created-with-version>
                    <updated-with-version>2020.1.202012300129 PE</updated-with-version>
                </metadata>
            </xf:instance>

            
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <attachments/>
            </xf:instance>

            
            <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-resources" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <resources>
                    <resource xml:lang="en">
                        <control-1>
                            <label>Select yes</label>
                            <hint/>
                        </control-1>
                        <control-2>
                            <label>Select yes again</label>
                            <hint/>
                        </control-2>
                        <control-3>
                            <label>Input number</label>
                            <hint/>
                        </control-3>
                        <control-5>
                            <label>But not now</label>
                            <hint/>
                        </control-5>
                        <control-6>
                            <text xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl" xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
                                  xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline">&lt;div&gt;Some text&lt;/div&gt;</text>
                        </control-6>
                        <section-1>
                            <label>Foo</label>
                        </section-1>
                        
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </xf:instance>

        </xf:model>
    </xh:head>
    <xh:body>
        <fr:view>
            <fr:body xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl" xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
                     xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">
                <fr:section id="section-1-section" bind="section-1-bind">
                    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/section-1/label"/>
                    <fr:grid id="grid-1-grid" bind="grid-1-bind">
                        <fr:c y="1" x="1" w="12">
                            <fr:yesno-input xmlns="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
                                            xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"
                                            id="control-1-control"
                                            bind="control-1-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-1/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-1/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                        
                        
                            </fr:yesno-input>
                                
                            </fr:c>
                        <fr:c x="1" y="2" w="12">
                            <fr:yesno-input xmlns="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
                                            xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"
                                            id="control-2-control"
                                            bind="control-2-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-2/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-2/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                        
                        
                            </fr:yesno-input>
                        </fr:c>
                        <fr:c x="1" y="3" w="12">
                            <fr:number xmlns="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
                                       xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"
                                       xmlns:NumberSupport="java:org.orbeon.xbl.NumberSupportJava"
                                       id="control-3-control"
                                       bind="control-3-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-3/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-3/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                        
                        
                            </fr:number>
                        </fr:c>
                        <fr:c x="1" y="4" w="12">
                            <fr:yesno-input xmlns="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
                                            xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"
                                            id="control-5-control"
                                            bind="control-5-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-5/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-5/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                        
                        
                            </fr:yesno-input>
                        </fr:c>
                        <fr:c x="1" y="5" w="12">
                            <fr:explanation xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl" id="control-6-control"
                                            bind="control-6-bind">
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                <fr:text ref="$form-resources/control-6/text" mediatype="text/html"/>
                            </fr:explanation>
                        </fr:c>
                    </fr:grid>
                </fr:section>
            </fr:body>
        </fr:view>
    </xh:body>
</xh:html>
```

`orbeon.log` is too long:
https://pastebin.pl/view/8f6e652d

---

How I use the embedding:

```html
<script>
    function embedForm() {
        ORBEON.fr.API.embedForm(
            document.getElementById("formEmbedder"),  
            "/orbeon",
            "Test",
            "EmbedJS",
            "new"
        );
    }
    
    embedForm();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Adrián, I'm sorry for the late response; somehow, I missed this! I've been trying to reproduce this, but it is working for me. I took your form above, renamed it to `orbeon/a`, deployed `orbeon-embedding.war` along Orbeon Forms, when to `http://localhost:8080/orbeon-embedding/?form=a`, and switch to the JavaScript API with the dropdown on top right. After that, here is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiVIR.gif, and I have no error in the console. Should I do anything different to reproduce this?

Comment: @avernet there is no mention of `orbeon-embedding.war` in the JS embedding API (https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/link-embed/javascript-api). It is only mentioned in Java embedding (https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/link-embed/java-api). Is it needed?

Comment: @avernet I don't really understand how you can access the `/orbeon-embedding/` path. `orbeon-embedding.war` was not deployed separately. However, `orbeon-embedding.jar` was also included in the deployed `orbeon.war` even though with a smaller size than the one from `orbeon-embedding.war`. Replacing the jar for the larger did not help.

Comment: You don't *need* to use the `orbeon-embedding.war` to use the JavaScript embedding API (and you're not expected to), but it just contains an example that uses the JavaScript embedding API, and thus is a good way to describe a problem in a way that is reproducible. Have you tried following the steps in my first comment above? Are you seeing something different if you go through those steps?

Comment: Hi Adrián, if this is still an issue you are dealing with, you'll let us know if you have a way to reproduce it. -Alex